# Outlook to future works

Tags: grammar

How to connect "outlook" and "future works"?

> 1. this report gives an outlook **to** future works

> 2. this report gives an outlook **on** future works

> 3. this report gives an outlook **for** future works

which one is fully correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook is a physical view (the outlook is of trees and woods), a general attitude towards life or aspects of life (he has an optimistic outlook), or a prediction (the outlook after Brexit is depressing). See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outlook

From any of these perspectives:

*this report gives an outlook to future works* reads awkwardly. If a physical analogue is desired, I would prefer the metaphorical *this report offers a window on future works*

*this report gives an outlook on future works* is acceptable

*this report gives an outlook for future works* is acceptable.

Comment: thanks a lot! your answer helps me a lot!

Comment: Very kind of you. Good Luck! I was expecting to be marked down by some Brexit enthusiast (they seem pretty quiet these days).

Answer (score 1):

I would say the second one. Giving an outlook to "future works" sounds odd for it seems to assume "future works" are some individuals perhaps, because that is who are supposed to have an outlook on something.